# Per Store Widget Instance Block References

Tags: theme, local.xml, widgets, theme-fallback, widget-instance

I have a multi store magento site set up. There is just the 2 Websites and a single store view each. They both use different themes of the same package.

Now setting up a block in `local.xml` of Website 1 (The Main Site) for the widgets block reference works fine I can see all my custom layout blocks available to use.

But in the second website in its separate theme if I create another block reference for a widget instance, it doesn't show in the block reference list in admin, but it does still show all the block references for website ones theme...

I have definitely set the layout and theme to point to my second theme for the second website and I'm definitely selecting the correct theme when setting up the widget instance.

You guys have any ideas?

Comment: FYI, If you are allowing Widgets to be created from admin then it needs to be created as per package/theme.